# Windows Update via Powershell IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update, wuapi

I am trying to install windows updates via PowerShell making use of COM objects from [WUApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/).

Here's the code I have got so far.

```
$updateSession = New-Object -com Microsoft.update.Session
$updateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$updateResult = $updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'");
$needsRestart = $false
foreach($update in $updateResult.Updates) {
    $needsRestart = $needsRestart -or $update.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior -ne 0
}
$updateDownloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
$updateDownloader.Updates = $updateResult.Updates
$downloadResult = $updateDownloader.Download()
```

When I run this code, I get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Update-Windows2.ps1:9 char:1
+ $updateDownloader.Updates = $updateResult.Updates
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException
```

I have checked and double checked and I can't seem to find where the issues is. I have tried similar logic with a C# code and that seems to be able assign the `Updates` variable fine without any issues.

Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unable to duplicate. It worked fine for me.

Comment: I did try again today and it doesn't happen any more. I think may be a machine restart may have fixed this issue. Think it may have been triggered due to a COM object memory leak. Thanks for the response anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce but am pretty sure that "$updateResult.Updates" is $null (= no updates available)
Can you please check?

If so, add an if condition ($null on the left side when used with collections!)

```bsh
if ($null -ne $updateResult.Updates) {
    $updateDownloader.Updates = $updateResult.Updates
    $downloadResult = $updateDownloader.Download()
}
```

Why $null on the left? (regardless of PS version):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.1#checking-for-null

Comment: Thanks for the response. Think a restart to the machine has fixed this issue for me. Could be some COM memory leak which may have triggered this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$updateSession = New-Object -com Microsoft.update.Session
$updateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$updateResult = $updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0").Update
$needsRestart = $false

If ($updateResult.Updates.Count -ne 0){
    foreach($update in $updateResult.Updates) {
        $needsRestart = $needsRestart -or $update.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior -ne 0
    }

    $updateDownloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $updateDownloader.Updates = $updateResult.Updates
    $downloadResult = $updateDownloader.Download()
}
Else{
    Write-Host "No have updates available"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).